Getting 401 error when try to verify subscription in android
I've implemented in app purchase in my application.
After purchasing a subscription I verify the subscription using the below API.
final String url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/$packageName/purchases/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/tokens/$token';
  print("verify URL $url");
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
    },
  );

I'm getting below response from above API.
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.",
                "domain": "androidpublisher",
                "reason": "permissionDenied"
            }
        ]
    }
}


From the error message it says the user (token) used for verify the subscription has  not this permission
